# javascript - addEventListener with an array of input

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I need to use `addEventListener` for automatically updating the values typed into different `input text` (actually 4 `input` tags)

Here's the HTML code :

```
<td class="col-md-4">
        <label for="lab1"><b>$\mathbf{M_{1}}$</b></label>                                
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab1" />                    
      </td>
        <td class="col-md-4">                                                            
        <label for="lab2"><b>$\mathbf{M_{2}}$</b></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab2"  />                   
      </td>
    <td class="col-md-4">                                                                
        <label for="lab3"><b>$\mathbf{M_{3}}$</b></label>                                
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab3" />                    
      </td>
      </tr>
   <tr>                                                                                  
       <td class="col-md-4">                                                             
        <label for="lab4"><b>$\mathbf{\Theta_{1}}$</b></label>                           
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lab4" />                    
      </td>
```

I would like to update values when they are modified, without having to click outside the `input`.

I tried to use the following `addModifyEvent` function in `main` :

```
    function addModifyEvent() {                                                              

     var inputList = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-control');   

    for (var i=0; i<inputList.length; i++)                                                   
     {  
    inputList[i].addEventListener('input', function()                                        
        {   
console.log(inputList[i].value);  });
    }       
    }
```

but it doesn't work ( I get `TypeError: inputList[i] is undefined`).

I don't know if I shoud better do :

```
inputList[i].addEventListener('inputList['+i+']',
```

or something closed instead of

```
inputList[i].addEventListener('input',
```

I want to add an `eventlistener` for each `input tag`.

Anyone could tell me the right syntax ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in example i printed 2 console one for your **input** and one for your **i**

**So your problem  is:**

> when in listener function you are trying to access
>   **console.log(inputList[i].value);** so at that time your **i** is  **4** and your input array length is **0-3** and because of **for loop** i will
>   be incremented to 4 so you got **undefined** because  **inputList[4]** is
>   not present in your array.

**Working example**:http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/gqce9htx/

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  console.log(input)
   for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
      input[i].addEventListener('input', function()
      {  
         console.log(input)
         console.log(i)
         console.log('input changed to: ', this.value);
      });

 }
```

debugg your error example:http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/gqce9htx/2/

Answer (score 0):

The context of the event handler is the input element the event is fired on. Replace the `inputList[i]` with `this`:

```
console.log(this.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of your code that uses `this.value` works just fine:

```
function addModifyEvent() {
    var inputList = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-control');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        inputList[i].addEventListener('input', function () {
            console.log(this.value);
        });
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9ny3wcxu/

---

You can't refer to `inputList[i]` inside the event handler because by the time the event handler is called (sometime later) the `for` loop has already finished running so `i` points past the end of the `inputList` HTMLCollection object.

You can solve the problem by just using `this` as a pointer to the object that caused the event and thus `this.value` is the value of the `input` field that has just been modified.

Answer (score 0):

At the time the event fires,

```
console.log(inputList[i].value);
```

`inputList[i]` will not be valid as it was part of the `for` loop used to bind event listeners.

Use `this` to get the current element on which the event was fired,

```
console.log(this.value);
```

---

Full code

```
function addModifyEvent() {
    var inputList = document.querySelectorAll('input.form-control');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
        inputList[i].addEventListener('input', function () {
            console.log(this.value);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures (if not familiar, please search it and read a bit). The code goes as below:

```
for (var i=0; i<inputList.length;i++)                                                   
{
     (function(i){
            inputList[i].addEventListener('input',function(){   
                  console.log(inputList[i].value);  });
         }
    })(i);
}
```

Basically the value of *i* remains intact within the function. This is required whenever you do something in a loop that is Async.  
The benefit being that you do not need to change the way you access values, except that you need to enclose them within a closure function. 
Hope this solves you issue without any changes in the way to want to access the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputElem.length; i++) {
inputElem[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(this.value);
}, false);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain in more detail why your code works and edit the code's format of your answer.